# 1 voltage regulator for all components or 1 voltage regulator for each component?

Tags: voltage-regulator

Is it a good idea to only put 1 5volts regulator to power all components or 1 5volts regulator for each component? If I only put 1 5volts regulator to power all the components would that affect, reduce or divide the 5 volts to power all the components?

The components that needs 5 volts power are ATMEGA328P, PCF8574P, 2x16 LCD Display, HX711, Load Cell, and 5 push buttons.

Comment: Ah, let me see. One servant for each child, IF you are a rich father.

Comment: How much current can regulator provide and how much current the loads need? Are loads sensitive to noise or not? Are there any reasons to keep them separate? Can you tell us why you chose to put a regulator for each component to begin with, so we can understand if it is a good idea or not.

Comment: A 7805 voltage regulator can output a max of 1.5A of current. You only need many voltage regulators if the components need a higher current than 7805 can output? I am worried that would affect or reduce the voltage when it is connected to many components.

Comment: @Tnek the 7805 or a linear converter is a special example.  It's horribly inefficient, so you don't give it big jobs.  If you need more than one 7805 you should be using something else in the first place, albeit sometimes only one of that thing.  Also, running a 7850 at 1 or 1.5A is not particularly easy (heat sink and fan setup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time it's better to have 1 regulator to power the whole board. The regulator should be chosen to be able to provide enough current.

That said, it is sometimes good to have several regulators in particular cases:

- You need a lot of currents and it is more cost-effective to have several regulators.
- Your board is big and want to segment the different area. This is often the case with computer motherboards.
- To separate digital and analog, you want to have a very low ripple filtered converter for the analog side.
- For a high uptime system like in medical you may want to have redundancy.
- Your board can accept extra modules plugged into it, in case those boards were faulty you still want the mainboard to run.
- You want to galvanically isolated some part of the board, for example for external input-output.